# UnsatisfiableError: conflict - keras-gpu - tensorflow-base

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda

Need help friends/ experts:I'm facing this issue below:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - keras-gpu
  - tensorflow-base
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Remove Tensorflow and install `tensorflow-gpu` as guided in the official docs, using `pip`, not `conda` https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Answer (score 1):

You should have installed the Keras GPU version and the TensorFlow CPU version caused the conflict. method 1: Re-create a TensorFlow-GPU environment under Anaconda Prompt using Pip to install TensorFlow-gpu and Keras, respectively. method 2: Under the Anaconda Navigator direct install Keras-gpu, this self dependent tensorFlow-gpu.